# Is this the right way to check the hash of uploaded file in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I don't find any example about how to upload file and the file hash in one request. So I think I should break it to two requests. But I don't know if it is right to do like below.

1. Client send the file hash to the server.
2. Server go to "wait for file" state, if not received file stream in 30 seconds, then back to "wait for hash" state
3. Client send file stream to server.
4. Server receive file stream and check the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the hash as a HTTP header.

Comment: yes, I can add hash to the HTTP header. I don't know how to describe that, maybe weird or broken? Because my codes all around classic web API controller, except this request. So I think there may be other  ways.

Comment: @T_T Sure there may be other ways.  However, using HTTP headers to send metadata, like hashes is exactly what they are for.  In fact there is even a notion of "trailer" header fields that allows you to send headers after the body so that you can calculate the hash on the fly.   Web API is a **HTTP** framework, it is intended that you use the features of HTTP to achieve your goals.